# Is there any easy way to check if a matrix is diagonalizable or not?

Tags: matrices

Wikipedia gives me,

> In linear algebra, a square matrix $A$ is called diagonalizable if it is similar to a diagonal matrix, i.e., if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{−1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix.

However, this condition is not very useful when checking for diagonalizability of a square matrix. Can you suggest me ways to check such a condition when just the matrix is given?

Comment: It's diagonalizable (over, say, the complex numbers – you do have to specify the field!) if there is a basis for ${\bf C}^n$ consisting entirely of eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If the matrix is symmetric, it is diagonalizable and the obtained matrix $P$ can be chosen to be orthogonal.
- If all the eigenvalues are distinct, then it is diagonalizable, i.e. An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable over the field $F$ if its charactheristic polynomial has $n$ distinct roots in $F$.
- If the sum of the dimension of the eigenspace is equal to $n$, then it is diagonalizable.

Comment: Your second statement does not hold in general.  Think of a $3\times3$ matrix with exact one eigenvalue with multiplicity one.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe maybe he did not mean "if and only if" but "one way if".

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A square matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its **minimal** polynomial is squarefree.

This needs a bit of explanation. The base field, the smallest field containing the entries of the matrix, may not contain all the roots of the minimal polynomial; for example, a real matrix and minimal $x^2 + 1.$ Furthermore, enlarging the field **does not change** the minimal polynomial.  However, it may allow us to factor, as in $x^2 + 1 = (x-i)(x+i).$ Here we can see clearly that the two linear factors are distinct. Put another way, the roots of the minimal polynomial in any field extension   are distinct.

By Cayley-Hamilton, we do not need to find roots to confirm the minimal polynomial, just find the lowest degree polynomial dividing the characteristic polynomial that annihilates the matrix.

See [Proposition 2.8 and Examples 2.9 in Michael Stoll](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/lecture-notes/LinearAlgebraII.pdf), on pages 5 and 6.